# When testing AJAX calls in JS with Jasmine, what is the difference between .andReturn(...) and .respondWith(...)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

When testing JavaScript code with the jasmine-ajax library, I can mock ajax responses. In particular, I can define the response that will be given to a particular ajax request. It seems that there are (at least) two different ways of doing this:

Approach #1:

```
jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
  status: 200,
  contentType: 'text/plain',
  responseText: 'my response'
});
```

Approach #2:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('my/url').andReturn({
  'responseText': 'my response'
});
```

If my `mostRecent` request is to the url `my/url`, then what else is the difference between these two?

I've been introduced to these two approaches in the "JavaScript Unit Testing" video series by M.E. Trostler, but I can't find a clear answer to my question in those videos, in a search of StackOverflow or in the Jasmine online documentation for its ajax.js plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging further on my own I believe that the difference between these two commands lies at least in part in the timing of the response from the mocked ajax call. In short:

- `respondWith` sends a response to a past unanswered ajax call now,
- `andReturn` establishes a response to be sent immediately upon a future ajax call being sent.

In the following 2 examples, verifying that the callback within the `onreadystatechange` handler shows whether or not a response to an ajax call has been returned, as such a response would trigger the callback. In approach #1, the ajax call is sent but remains unanswered until `respondWith` is called. In approach #2, the response is pre-set such that as soon as the ajax call is sent, a response is returned.

Approach #1:

```
setUpAndSendAjaxCall1();
expect(onreadystatechangeCallback1).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
  ...
  "responseText": "response #1"
});
expect(onreadystatechangeCallback1).toHaveBeenCalledWith("response #1");
```

Approach #2:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(myUrl).andReturn({
  ...
  "responseTest": "response #2"
});
setUpAndSendAjaxCall2();
expect(onreadystatechangeCallback2).toHaveBeenCalledWith("response #2");
```